# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’:

Tags: java, loading, rweka

Im getting this error, when i execute Library(Rweka). try to help me in resolving this error. i have jdk 1.8. and R 3.5 installed.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/prajj/Documents/R/R-3.5.0rc/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Does the directory you posted exist? I was getting the same error, then read [this](https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/). Turns out I was on a new machine that didn't yet have Java installed. After picking the right version (64 instead of 32 bit) then installing, my error went away and it now works fine.